# Have I been banned or punished in stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion

First, I know I should not be posting this here, but I am desperate and I don't know where else to try.

Basically, since yesterday I lost my ability to answer to comments on my own questions. In fact, all I can do is post more questions. I checked my reputation, and I have 81 (which I assume will get downvotes from you guys because I should not be posting it here) and iirc I should be able to answer to comments with 81 rep.

I am sorry I have to post this question here, but since I am new I don't know who I can talk with to solve the problem (don't know any mods), and as I stated before I am also quite desperate.

I also tried to read the FAQ link in the top of the page but it didn't help me.

The way I see I didn't break any forum rules, so I really dont understand this.

Apologies for the wall of text, and thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't been banned, your c++ question gained a lot of down votes bringing your karma below 100 which is required to answer comments.  don't worry about it, be a good citizen and it will get back over 100 again..

Comment: Apologies for the duplicate, I have created the other question before realizing this one had been moved. How can I fix it?

Comment: You don't need to do anything at this point, this one will get closed as a duplicate of that one and life will move on happily.

Comment: @ilanberci isn't it 50 rep To comment everywhere .?